# React function re-mounting multiple times

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, websocket, socket.io, mern

**Title:** Issue with managing messages in React components

**Question:**

I'm encountering an issue with managing messages in my React application, particularly with the `Message` and `MessageList` components. The `Message` component is responsible for displaying individual messages, while the `MessageList` component renders a list of messages and handles scrolling.

The `Message` component fetches messages from an API and updates the state accordingly. However, I'm facing issues with updating and displaying messages correctly. Additionally, the scrolling behavior in the `MessageList` component seems to be inconsistent.

Below are the code snippets for both components:

**Message Component:**

```js
import React, { memo, useMemo, useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import API_BASE_URL from './apiConfig';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import img from '../styles/user1.png';
import messageSound from '../styles/sound/send.mp3';
import clickSound from '../styles/sound/clicktoggle.mp3';
import doc from '../styles/doc.png';


const messageSoundRef = new Audio(messageSound);
const clickSoundRef = new Audio(clickSound);

function Primary({ data: { user, text, time, message_id, documentName, contentType, content }, onDelete }) {
}
function Secondary({ data: { user, text, time, documentName, contentType, content, status }, onReply, currentUser }) {
}
function Message({ selectedUser, userSession }) {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const handleDeleteMessage = useCallback(async (deletedMessageId) => {
    try {      
      // Delete the message locally
      const updatedMessages = messages.filter((message) => message._id['$oid'] !== deletedMessageId['$oid']);
      setMessages(updatedMessages);
      localStorage.setItem('messages', JSON.stringify(updatedMessages));

      // Fetch new messages after deleting
      const response = await axios.post(API_BASE_URL + '/api/getMessages', {
        userId: userSession,
        otherUserId: selectedUser || 'Customer Support',
      });
  
      const newMessages = response.data.messages;
  
      setMessages(newMessages);
      localStorage.setItem('messages', JSON.stringify(newMessages));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error deleting or fetching messages:', error);
    }
  }, [messages, userSession, selectedUser]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        // Clear previous messages
        setMessages([]);

        // Fetch new messages
        const response = await axios.post(API_BASE_URL + '/api/getMessages', {
          userId: userSession,
          otherUserId: selectedUser || 'Customer Support',
        });

        const newMessages = response.data.messages;
        // Update local state
        setMessages(newMessages);

        // Save to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('messages', JSON.stringify(newMessages));
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching messages:', error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [userSession, selectedUser]);

  // Memoize displayed messages to prevent unnecessary re-renders
  const displayedMessages = useMemo(() => {
    // Sort messages by date and time
    const sortedMessages = messages
      .slice()
      .sort((a, b) => {
        const dateA = new Date(`${a.date} ${a.time}`);
        const dateB = new Date(`${b.date} ${b.time}`);
        return dateA - dateB;
      })
      .sort((a, b) => {
        // Secondary sorting by message_id (or any other unique identifier)
        return a.message_id - b.message_id;
      });
  
    return sortedMessages.map((message) => {
      const messageProps = {
        id: message._id,
        user: message.sender,
        text: message.chat,
        time: `${message.date} ${message.time}`,
        message_id: message.message_id,
        documentName: message.documentName,
        contentType: message.contentType,
        content: message.content,
      };
  
      return message.sender === userSession ? (
        <Primary key={message._id} data={messageProps} currentUser={userSession} onDelete={handleDeleteMessage} />
      ) : (
        <Secondary key={message._id} data={messageProps} currentUser={userSession} />
      );
    });
  }, [messages, userSession, handleDeleteMessage]);  

  // Render the displayed messages
  return <>{displayedMessages}</>;
}

export default memo(Message);
```

**MessageList Component:**

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Message from './Message';
import down  from '../styles/down.png';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

function MessageList({ messages, userSession, selectedUser, onReply }) {
  const messageListRef = useRef(null);
  const [shouldScrollDown, setShouldScrollDown] = useState(false);
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldScrollDown) {
      messageListRef.current.scrollTop = messageListRef.current.scrollHeight;
      setShouldScrollDown(false);
    }
  }, [shouldScrollDown]);

  const handleScrollDown = () => {
    setShouldScrollDown(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="message-list-container">
      <div ref={messageListRef} className="columns is-multiline has-text-black has-background-white-bis messagelist scrollable-content" style={{ alignContent: 'flex-start', overflowY: 'auto', maxHeight: '400px' }}>
        {messages.map((message, index) => (
          <Message onReply={(text) => onReply(text)} key={index} data={message} userSession={userSession} selectedUser={selectedUser} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div title={t('scroll')} className="scroll-down-button" onClick={handleScrollDown}>
        <img alt='Scroll Down' className='down' src={down}></img>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MessageList;
```

I'm encountering the following problems:

1. The messages are not being displayed correctly, and there seems to be an issue with updating the messages state in the `Message` component.
2. The scrolling behavior in the `MessageList` component is inconsistent, and messages are not always scrolled to the bottom as expected.

I've attempted the following:

- Ensured that the API calls to fetch messages are successful.
- Checked for any errors or warnings in the console.
- Reviewed the state management logic in both components.
- Experimented with different approaches for updating and displaying messages.

Despite these efforts, I haven't been able to resolve the issues. I'm seeking assistance in understanding what might be causing these problems and how to address them effectively. To better illustrate the problem, I've included screenshots below:

- [Screenshot of the app when i first login display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx1H6.png)
- [Screenshot of the app when someone login or new message comes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFdHf.png)

Any insights, suggestions, or guidance would be highly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

---

**Sys-Requirements**

```
npm version
```

```
{
  'bizmo-chat': '1.0.0',
  npm: '8.19.4',
  node: '16.20.1',
  v8: '9.4.146.26-node.26',
  uv: '1.43.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.19.1',
  modules: '93',
  nghttp2: '1.47.0',
  napi: '8',
  llhttp: '6.0.11',
  openssl: '1.1.1u+quic',
  cldr: '41.0',
  icu: '71.1',
  tz: '2022f',
  unicode: '14.0',
  ngtcp2: '0.8.1',
  nghttp3: '0.7.0'
}
```

Comment: You now have a `Message` component that holds a state atom `messages` and updates it by itself. That's probably absolutely not what you want.